# How do I report sex differences in meta-analysis when some studies included only report data for one sex?

Tags: meta-analysis

I am completing a meta-analysis of the sex differences in athlete ECGs. I have included studies that only talk about one sex to broaden the amount of data included. Is there a way to meta-analyse female vs male data when not all the studies have female and male participants?
There are both continuous and dichotomous variables in this data.